# Testing arduino gps

Tags: c++, testing, gps, arduino, system

Me and and a friend of mine are building a  robot which contains a gps for arduino. We built the following circuit, to test the gps:

[image: Arduino circuit]

We're trying the following code to test the gps:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS.h>

long lat,lon; // create variable for latitude and longitude object

SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(2, 3); // create gps sensor connection
TinyGPS gps; // create gps object

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600); // connect serial
  gpsSerial.begin(4800); // connect gps sensor
}

void loop(){
  Serial.print("test");     //I implemented this test
  while(gpsSerial.available()){ // check for gps data
    Serial.print("test2");     //I implemented this test
   if(gps.encode(gpsSerial.read())){ // encode gps data
     Serial.print("test3");       //I implemented this test
    gps.get_position(&lat,&lon); // get latitude and longitude
    // display position
    Serial.print("Position: ");
    Serial.print("lat: ");Serial.print(lat);Serial.print(" ");// print latitude
    Serial.print("lon: ");Serial.println(lon); // print longitude
   }
  }
}
```

The thing is that the serial monitor does output test number 1, but doesn't output test number 2 and number 3. So we expected the circuit we built to fail. But we double checked the wires etc. Does anybody know what the problem could be?

Any inspiration/help is welcome,

Thanks,

Justin van Til

Comment: Try to be precise in your problem description.  Does "does output test number 1, but doesn't output test number 2 and 3" mean that it outputs "test" but not "test2" or "test3"  If so, say that.   Assuming that is the problem then either gps.encode() never returns, or it returns false.   Add additional print statements to determine which of those cases is happening. (i.e. add some else clauses)

Comment: Yeah you are right. I did not descriped the problem precise enough. You are right though. So "test" gets printed but "test2" and "test2" don't. So I assume as you do that the "while" statement is false. I have no idea though how I would get the "gpsSerial.available()" true. 

Thanks for your clear response and I hope you can help me further.

Comment: I did not assume that the while statement is false.  I said that was one of two possibilities.   You should verify which of those possibilities is happening so you don't waste time solving the wrong one.   Assuming that `available()` does return false, you can  1) examine the source code of the `available()` method if you have access to it; or 2) read the documentation for the method very carefully to see what it is checking for; or 3) contact the author of the available method and ask them what it is checking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>    
#include <TinyGPS.h>    
TinyGPS gps;          

static void print_long(long val, long invalid, int len, int prec);          
static void print_int(unsigned long val, unsigned long invalid, int len);      
static void print_date(TinyGPS &gps);                                          
static void print_str(const char *str, int len);                                

SoftwareSerial ss(3,4);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);       
  ss.begin(9600);        
 }

void loop()
{

  long lat, lon;
  int alt;

  unsigned short sentences = 0, failed = 0;
  gps.get_position(&lat, &lon);
  alt=gps.altitude();

  Serial.print("CURRENT LATITUDE & LONGITUDE:");
  Serial.print(lat);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(lon);
  Serial.print("CURRENT ALTITUDE:");
  Serial.println(alt);
  smartdelay(1000); 
}


static void smartdelay(unsigned long ms)
{
  unsigned long start = millis();
  do 
  {
    while (ss.available())
      gps.encode(ss.read());
  } while (millis() - start < ms);
}

static void print_long (long val, long invalid, int len, int prec)  
{
  if (val == invalid)
  {
    while (len-- > 1)
      Serial.print('*');
    Serial.print(' ');
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(val, prec);
    int vi = abs((int)val);
    int flen = prec + (val < 0.0 ? 2 : 1); // . and -
    flen += vi >= 1000 ? 4 : vi >= 100 ? 3 : vi >= 10 ? 2 : 1;
    for (int i=flen; i<len; ++i)
      Serial.print(' ');
  }
  smartdelay(0);
}


static void print_int(unsigned long val, unsigned long invalid, int len)
{
  char sz[32];
  if (val == invalid)
    strcpy(sz, "*******");
  else
    sprintf(sz, "%ld", val);
  sz[len] = 0;
  for (int i=strlen(sz); i<len; ++i)
    sz[i] = ' ';
  if (len > 0) 
    sz[len-1] = ' ';
  Serial.print(sz);
  smartdelay(0);
}
static void print_str(const char *str, int len)
{
  int slen = strlen(str);
  for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
    Serial.print(i<slen ? str[i] : ' ');
  smartdelay(0);
}
```